# Custom Cross Validating and Validation with extremly imbalanced classes

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree, cross-validation, confusion-matrix

I have a multi-class problem with highly imbalanced data.

Their is one large majority class with a few thousand members, some classes with 100-1000 members, and 10-30 classes with only 1 member.

Sampling isn't possible because it could lead to a wrong weight of the classes.

To evaluate my model I want to use cross validation. I tried `cross_val_predict(x,y, cv=10)` which lead to the error-code:

> Warning: The least populated class in y has only 1 members, which is too few. The minimum number of members in any class cannot be less than n_splits=10.

I tried to build my own cross-validation, which is pretty straight forward.

I split my data via [StratifiedKFold](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html) and then did the following:

```
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier()

for ta, te in splits
    xTrain, xTest = x.iloc[ta], x.iloc[te]
    yTrain, yTest = y.iloc[ta], y.iloc[te]
    clf.fit(xTrain, yTrain)
    prediction = clf.predict(xTest)
    cnf_matrix[ta] = confusion_matrix(yTest, prediction)
    classRepo[ta] = classification_report(y, prediction)
```

Because I am working in jupyter notebook I have to print every position of the `cnf_matrix` and `classRepo` by hand and go through it by myself.

Is there a more elegant solution like fusing the `classRepo` and `cnf_matrix` by hand, so that I can get the same result as `cross_val_predict(x,y, cv=x)` offers?

Is there a better metric to tackle my problem?

Comment: It is impossible to create stratified splits, when there are classes with only 1 member. This is not a limitation by any implementation.

Comment: but with StratifiedKFold i actually can split the dataset

Comment: The splits will not be stratified completely. There will be folds where either training or test set won't contain the singleton classes. Thus the warning by scikit-learn.

Comment: But if i use StratifiedKFolds and the code provided all of my confusion matrix display all of the classes for every split. the error only appears if i try cros_val_predict.

Comment: If you are running the code exactly as it appears in your question you aren't actually fitting on the train and test splits anyway. In your example, you are repeatedly training on `XTa`, `yTa`, not your splits of `xTrain`, `yTrain`. That might exlain your predictions containing all classes.

Comment: Sorry - i made an mistake while transfering the code into the question. i am fitting the model with xTrain and yTrain.

Comment: I don't think your decision tree is going to do anything useful for a class with a single observation. It might make sense for you to group some of the labels together in this case.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion - how would this actually work?

Answer (score 1):

"Sampling isn't possible because it could lead to a wrong weight of the classes."

That is a strong assertion as you are assuming that your training data is a perfect representation of all remaining, an future observable data. If I was on your team, I would challenge you to support that hypothesis with experimental data.

There are in fact many approaches developed specifically for dealing with minority class imbalances. For example [SMOTE](https://jair.org/index.php/jair/article/view/10302) and [ADASYN](https://sci2s.ugr.es/keel/pdf/algorithm/congreso/2008-He-ieee.pdf). I would point you towards, [imbalanced learn](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/imbalanced-learn#imbalanced-learn) for a python package that implements these and other techniques within the sklearn framework.

Comment: Thank you for this answer and suggestion. The classes with one member are classified by an exact combination of features. therefor a synthetic approach would possibly lead to a faulty prediction.

Comment: if i would use SMOTE afaik it is necessary to split training and test data before the oversampling so that i dont run into overoptimistic predictions through synthesized test data. but if it isnt even possible to split, cause of the restriction in the implementations - what options do i have left?

Comment: That's a fair point for singletons. I think @Dan has the right idea by grouping some of these together if you can't collect more data. Something like a nearest neighbors approach may help you decrease your classes.

Comment: I've never heard about it - what is grouping the classes all about? and if each of the classes needs to stand by itself and should never under absolutly no circumstances be mixed with another class, is it still usable? feels like i am in a dead end.

Comment: Well you've described a situation where you have ~ 30 classes as singletons and thousands of total classes. That level of granularity might be overkill. It's kind of hard to really say without knowing what domain you are working in and the context of the task.